# How to extract spatial attributes of polygons in qgis?

Tags: geospatial, qgis, spatial-query

I have a .shp file which contains polygons each of them representing one building. I would like to extract the x and y coordinates of each polygon as a row to a .csv file.
I could creat corner of polygons in points but I do not know how to extract points of each polygon separately as a row to .csv file.
Below is a picture of what I have done so far.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the geom_to_wkt (well-known text) function in the field calculator to create a new field:

```
geom_to_wkt($geometry)
```

This creates a text representation of the polygon as a single row. You could then export the attribute table to a csv.  When you export (save as..), go to layer options and change the separator to semicolon, otherwise you will end up with problems.

Depending on your fluency with R or python, there would be ways to access the coordinates using a short script as well.